# An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command in Safari.

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io, safaridriver

Having this error while trying to set the value of the textbox to blank in Safari 10.1.

**Using WebdriverIO: 4.6.2**

**Scenario:** Got a text already in the textbox. Have to make that textbox blank to reset the search.

**Code Snippet:**

```
$(elementSelector).setValue('');
browser.waitUntil(() =>{
  //Some conditions to meet after reset
});
```

**Error:**

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 11 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'mac-185-44-130-79.browserstack.com', ip: '185.44.130.79', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.5', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, version=12604.1.22, cleanSession=true, platform=MAC, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=safari, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=macOS, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 89FDFB29-FF29-4DE0-B7D2-709AA0E86726
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with selenium webdriver-io while running against chrome. Did you find a reason/solution for this error?